# How do I sum the available hours in a given period in PowerBI based on the following?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have some data I am working with that has the number of minutes someone works in a given day
I would like to sum this amount based on the filter context being daily weekly monthly etc

`

```
Utilization_Rate =
        Var Actual_Job_Length =
                SUMX( 
                    FILTER(
                            MATCHED_JOBID,
                            MATCHED_JOBID[ACTUAL_END]>MATCHED_JOBID[ACTUAL_START]),
                    DATEDIFF(
                            MATCHED_JOBID[ACTUAL_START],
                            MATCHED_JOBID[ACTUAL_END],
                            MINUTE))

        VAR UTILIZATION =
                        DIVIDE( Actual_Job_Length, TIME AVAILABLE)
RETURN UTILIZATION
```

`

My issue is with this time available function. I want to be able to utilization based on the day, week start date, month, quarter, and year
I need to sum the available hours based on a 5 day work week. If a employee works more than 30 they must have 8 hour days (fulltime) if an employee works 30 or less then 6 hour days.

I do not know how to do the above and have function for different period lengths. If I need multiple measures that is fine too. Just don't know how to approach it

I have not figured out anything to do

I got further

```
  PT-FT = 
            CALCULATE(IF( [Total_Job_Duration]>= VALUES('Calendar Lookup'[PT_hours]), VALUES('Calendar Lookup'[FT_Hours]), VALUES('Calendar Lookup'[PT_hours])), FILTER(Matched_JobID, Matched_JobID[Actual_Start].[Date]))
```

This works to some extent but I still have a problem with it not summing for the number of work days in a period

[Result of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfNBV.png)

I want it for example in this case to sum for the week as the other values have so I would see 40 instead of 8 and 30 instead of 6

Comment: I have gotten further

Comment: Please share the datasets, not the final Matrix visual! What a nice that you shared your effort (DAX Code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below measure. Its working fine at my end:

```
Quantity_based_OnSlicer = 
var Daily = SELECTEDVALUE('Product'[Date])
var Monthly = year(selectedvalue('Product'[Date])) & MONTH(SELECTEDVALUE('Product'[Date]))
var weekly = WEEKNUM(SELECTEDVALUE('Product'[Date]))
Return
SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE('Ex5-Slicer'[Value]),
    "Daily",CALCULATE(SUM('Product'[Quantity]),'Product'[Date] = Daily,ALLEXCEPT('Product','Product'[Date])),
     "Monthly",CALCULATE(SUM('Product'[Quantity]),year('Product'[Date])&month('Product'[Date]) = Monthly,ALLEXCEPT('Product','Product'[Date])),
     "Weekly",CALCULATE(SUM('Product'[Quantity]),WEEKNUM('Product'[Date]) = weekly,ALLEXCEPT('Product','Product'[Date])),
     0
)
```

[image]